Versions of Margulis lemma in hyperbolic space
I have seen several versions of Margulis lemma, treating elliptic elements diffenrently. I have problem in undertanding the version in Thurston's The Geometry and Topology of 3-Manifold, where it is stated as

Lemma 5.10.1  For every dimension n, there is a $\epsilon(n)>0$ s.t. for every discrete group $\Gamma$ of isometry of $ H^n$ and any $x\in H^n$, $\Gamma_\epsilon'(x)$ is Abelian and $\Gamma_\epsilon(x)$ has a Abelian subgroup of finite index.

Where $\Gamma_\epsilon(x)$ is the subgroup of $\Gamma$ generated by $\{g|d(g.x,x)<\epsilon\}$, and $\Gamma_\epsilon'(x) \subset\Gamma_\epsilon(x)$ is the sbgroup containing the elements "with derivative $\epsilon$-close to identity". And I am not able to make the bold phrase rigorous. The naive understanding for such an isometry $\phi$ is that (restricted to dimension=3), in the upper halfspace modle the derivative of $\phi$ at x, which is a $3\times3$ matrix, is $\epsilon$-close to identity; I think this understanding is equivalent to that, $\phi$ is $\epsilon$-close (not the same $\epsilon$) to identity in $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$. However, these understanding clearly do not satisfy the crutial properties in the context:

the elements in $\Gamma_\epsilon(x)$ with derivative $\epsilon$-close to identity form a subgroup
if $\phi_1$, $\phi_2$ moves x a distance< some $\epsilon_1$, the derivative of $\phi_1\phi_2$ can be estimated by $\epsilon_2\times$derivative of $\phi_1\times$derivative of $\phi_2$

(e.g. $\phi $ is a translation along some geodesic, $\phi^n$ moves x a long distance and has derivative (the naive undertading of derivative) far away from identity)
I have searched other books, such as Hyperbolic Manifolds and Kleinian Groups (Katsuhiko Matsuzaki, Masahiko Taniguchi) Thm 2.23, they changed the derivative condition to that $\Gamma$ is torsion free, which does not deal with elliptic element at all. And in Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds (John G. Ratcliffe)  Thm 12.5.1 neither of these conditions is applied, and the theorem actually looks wrong (e.g. SO(3) acting as rotations around x is non-Abelian).
But amoung these versions of Margulis lemma, Thurston's version is the strongest, so I wonder how to correctly interpret it i.e. how to correctly interpret $\Gamma_\epsilon'(x)$.

Thurston's formulation of the lemma is simply wrong. The definition of $\Gamma'_\epsilon(x)$ should be as the subgroup generated by elements $g$ such that $d(x,gx)<\epsilon$ and $||Dg_x -Id||<\epsilon$. Here I am using the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic space. There are more intrinsic ways to define closeness of the derivative to the identity, but they require some background in differential geometry (parallel transport), I am not sure you know this.

I can think of a way to intrinsically compare derivatives at x of two diffeoms $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ in hyperbolic space: we can parallel transport $d\phi_1$, as a (1,1)-form, along the unique geodesic between $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$. Is this the way you mentioned?

Right...........

Yes, that definition of $\Gamma'_\epsilon$ is not correct. If you read the second and third sentences of the proof of Thurston's Lemma 5.10.1, you will see that the definition of $\Gamma'_\epsilon$ is correctly stated there: ... if $\Gamma'_\epsilon$ is any discrete subgroup of $G$ generated by small elements...
One thing to keep in mind in this passage is that $G$ represents a Lie group, every Lie group is a differentiable manifold, and every differentiable manifold has a metric that generates its topology. In this context a "small" element is an element whose distance from the identity element is bounded above by some specified constant; so, for example, $\Gamma'_\epsilon$ is the subgroup of $\Gamma$ generated by elements whose distance from the identity is $\le \epsilon$.
As alluded to in your post, if you are in a matrix group then you can measure distance between two matrices $A,B$ using the matrix norm $d(A,B)=\|A-B\|$, and so distance from a matrix $M$ to the identity element $I$ is given by $d(M,I)=\|M-I\|$ (this metric is not invariant under the group action in any way, but for purposes of your post that is not important).
For the group of isometries of $\mathbb H^3$ one can, as you say, use the matrix group $PSL(2,\mathbb C)$. More generally, in the context of Lemma 5.10.1, for the group of isometries of $\mathbb H^n$ one can use $SO_+(n,1)$.
